# Adding query string parameters to URL with same name as custom post type gives 404 error

Tags: redirect, query-string

I have a Projects page where I use query strings to deep-link to different categories using JavaScript. For example if my URL is `www.mysite.com/projects/?theme=blue` then I read this query string in JavaScript and load the results using Ajax. I'm only reading the query string in JavaScript, not PHP/WordPress.

The problem is one of my query parameters is named `theme`, but I also have a custom post type named `theme`. It's giving me a 404 error any time I have `theme` in the URL. On just the Projects page, is it possible to tell WordPress not to process any query string variables?

Comment: The usual way to pass parameters with JavaScript is the `#` symbol, not a query string.

Comment: I wanted the URLs to be indexable by search engines as well. As far as I know Google doesn't usually index anchor links in URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I figured it out.

When calling the `register_post_type` function, the arguments array should set the `'query_var'` property to `false`.